# Difference Between NULL and Zero in Comparing

Tags: c++, c, null, nullptr

I know a little bit about NULL, but when it comes to comparing I get confused.
For Example:

```
int* p;
if(p == NULL){
//do stuff
}
if(p == 0){
//do stuff
}
```

In the first comparison "p" compares with what address?

Is it looking for the reference point of "p", and seeing if it is valid or not?

Comment: "I know that" followed by something completely absurd.

Comment: `I know that NULL is a empty space in memory`...how? Any reference?

Comment: Please use either the C or C++ tag; they are separate languages.

Comment: Avoid writing multi-language source files. That is extremely hard work and it almost never has any advantage to writing single language source files. IOW: stick to one of C or C++.

Comment: "and see if it is valid or not" A pointer not being `NULL` does not mean, that the pointer is valid.

Comment: Why would this question attract so many down votes? Isn't down votes supposed to mean a badly phrased question? This question is as clear as it is and this is a question many new learners will ask.

Comment: @user3437460: See the tool-tip. DVs are also for badly researched questions. And there is enough information about `NUL`, _null pointer constants_ and _null pointers_ to be found. And adding tags for two different languages certainly is another reason.

Comment: @Tarik: `NULL` exists in C++ too. Don't just remove a tag.

Comment: @Olaf: Any reason you are throwing `NUL` into the ring in addition to all the rest?

Comment: @Deduplicator: The most obvious reason: A typo!

Comment: Gigili awoke on the morning of the 11th of January 2016 not knowing that today he would break StackOverflow.

Comment: @Olaf: And here I thought you wanted to completely confuse everyone. ;-)

Comment: @Deduplicator: Why should I? OP is already confused enough ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In every modern implementation of C, NULL is zero, usually as a pointer value:

```
#define  NULL  (void *) 0
```

So comparing, say, a character to NULL is likely to be invalid:

```
char ch = 'a';
if (ch == NULL)     //  probably "invalid comparison of pointer with scalar"
```

As a pointer value, NULL chosen to point to invalid memory so that dereferencing it (on a suitable architecture) will cause a memory fault.  Most virtual machines reserve lower memory just for this purpose and implemented by leaving low memory unmapped to physical memory.  How much memory is unreserved?  Could be a few kilobytes, but many implementations reserve a few megabytes.

Comment: This answer is definitely wrong for C++ (can’t say for C).

Comment: @KonradRudolph:  I am answering for C, but why do you say it is "definitely wrong for C++"?

Comment: Well because it is: the answer is incorrect for C++, and the question was tagged [tag:c++] (and [tag:c]).

Comment: Ah, alright: in C++ `NULL`, is identical to the literal `0`.

Comment: `NULL` as a macro cannot be the value of a pointer. You mena a _null pointer_, which is related, yet something different.

Comment: @Olaf:  Please clarify.

Comment: What do you not understand? See the C standard; the terms are well-defined. And `NULL` is not necessarily "zero". I would not go that far to state that for "every modern implementation". It just does not care. In C++ things are even more complicated, considering `nullptr`.

Comment: Comparing an integer type to a pointer converts the pointer to an integer. While a compiler should warn, it is still valid code.

Comment: "will cause a memory fault" - that is false.  If address zero happens to be your interrupt vector table and you have no MMU, you will overwrite your interrupt vector table.  It's happened to me.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Sometimes. Sometimes it's `nullptr`.

Comment: @Deduplicator How terrible! This silently breaks old code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Only code which is *already* broken. And silently? Sometimes, sometimes not.

Comment: @Deduplicator Admittedly, there are worse things. :-)

Comment: @MartinBonner: That's why I put so much emphasis on the difference between `NULL`, _null pointer (constant)_ and `0`. It is one of the largest flaws in C not to provide a specific keyword for a _null pointer constant_ like other languages that time did (e.g. Pascal). C++11 tried to change that, but not C.

Answer (score 3):

From the C99 Standard:

> **7.17 Common definitions `<stddef.h>`**
>
> 3 The macros are
>
> ```
> NULL
> ```
>
> which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant; ...

From the C++11 Standard:

> **18.2 Types**
>
> 3 The macro `NULL` is an implementation-defined C++ null pointer constant in this International Standard (4.10).<sup>194</sup>

Footnote 194:

> 194) Possible definitions include `0` and `0L`, but not `(void*)0`.

Microsoft VS 2008 defines it as:

```
/* Define NULL pointer value */
#ifndef NULL
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define NULL    0
#else
#define NULL    ((void *)0)
#endif
#endif
```

gcc/g++ 4.9.3 defines it as:

```
#if defined (_STDDEF_H) || defined (__need_NULL)
#undef NULL     /* in case <stdio.h> has defined it. */
#ifdef __GNUG__
#define NULL __null
#else   /* G++ */
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define NULL ((void *)0)
#else   /* C++ */
#define NULL 0
#endif  /* C++ */
#endif  /* G++ */
#endif  /* NULL not defined and <stddef.h> or need NULL.  */
```

I suspect other modern compilers define it similarly.

Given the above definitions of `NULL`, the line

```
if(p == NULL){
```

expands to:

```
if(p == ((void*)0) ){
```

in C.

It expands to

```
if(p == 0){
```

in C++.

In other C++ compilers, that line could expand to

```
if(p == 0L){
```

When using C++11, it is better to avoid `NULL` and start using [`nullptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) instead.

```
if ( p == nullptr ) {
```

Comment: Sometimes, your expansions are right... sometimes not.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, `NULL` is a singular pointer-value pointing nowhere, and implicitly convertible to any pointer-type.
Practically, you unfortunately cannot depend on it behaving as a pointer value unless you use it in a pointer-only context.

Thus, use `nullptr` in C++11 and later respectively 0 cast to the right pointer-type, especially in contexts where an integral zero would not be converted to a pointer.

BTW: While on most modern systems a null pointer is really all-bits-zero, that's not required by the standard (there might be many bit-patterns representing null pointers, and none all-zero), and doesn't make any difference to how a null pointer constant is represented in source code.

---

In C++:

> The macro `NULL` is an implementation-defined C++ null pointer constant in this International Standard (4.10).

Which is defined as:

> A null pointer constant is an integer literal (2.14.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

Pre-C++11 the last option was obviously not available...
And post-C++11, because you do not know what it is, you should use `nullptr` directly.

---

In C:

> The macros are
>   `NULL`
>   which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant; ...

Which is defined as:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a null pointer constant.

Answer (score 3):

NULL represents a value that is not used by any valid pointer. So, if a pointer is NULL, it points to no variable at all. In pointer contexts, the value zero means the same thing as NULL, however it is clearer to use NULL instead of zero. That's all you need to know about NULL.

Comment: It isn't irrelevant that `NULL` in a *non-pointer-context* might not be a pointer at all.

Comment: @Deduplicator Why would NULL appear in a non-pointer context?

Comment: Think of any variadic function, but C++ variadic templates. Or think of overloads in C++.

Comment: @Deduplicator Indeed, but with variadic functions all hope is gone when it comes to type safety.

Comment: How about C11 generic macros?

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` in C++ compilers is just a macro defining a "null pointer constant" (generally of value 0). So there is no difference, apart from `NULL` being used to indicate an intent (which is important). For example you can create an `int` variable with the value `NULL`, which is not given any special treatment over the standard declaration (`int a = 0;`).

`NULL` is **NOT** "an empty space in memory". It is just a symbol that (generally) represents an absence of something (value, pointer etc...).

However using of `NULL` is now discouraged in C++ and the far superior **[nullptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr)** should be used instead.

Comment: `NULL` does not define the integer value `0`, but **a** _null pointer constant_. And there is one of the differences between C++ and C. And there is a a fundamental difference between a _null pointer_ and a _null pointer constant_.

Comment: And in C++ the reserved name `nullptr` shall be used. `std::nullptr_t` is its type. Not sure though where you would need that type, though.

Comment: If you wanted your own value to represent a `null`?

Comment: What is a `null`? If you really want to obfuscate your code, `#define null nullptr`. This is the same as Pythons `NoneType`: There is exactly one object with that type: `None`.

Comment: I just mean a `thing` called "null". You could I suppose do something like this `std::nullptr_t null;`. I've not tried it but it would be interesting to see what exactly that would do. Would `null == nullptr`?

Comment: If `NULL` is not a macro defining a null pointer constant, it isn't a C++ compiler!

Comment: You might mean a _null pointer_. `null` is just an arbitrary name, `NULL` is a macro required by the standard (C and C++). Please use standard terminology. FYI: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html

Comment: @Dennis: Not sure about C++, but in C, _null pointers have to match `(void *)0`, even if they have different representation (e.g. encode the type).

Comment: @Olaf: Both C and C++ only require that all null pointers (after conversion) compare equal, and that a null pointer constant results in one, whatever bit-pattern it might have.

Comment: @MartinBonner - Sorry, previously I has no parenthesis in the sentence, so the "most" applied to the value of 0. There is nothing to say another value could not be used. 
@Olaf - The snippet I had above was pure speculation based on your statement: "Not sure though where you would need that type, though". Just saying that you can in fact declare `nullptr_t` variables.

Comment: @Deduplicator: The first part is the same as I stated. Not sure what you mean with "results in one". There is no requirement for a single _null pointer constant_ (the C standard at least clearly uses "**a** null pointer constant", not "**the** ..."). Note that a variable may be a _null pointer_, but - obviously - not a _null pointer constant_.

Answer (score 1):

> know that NULL is a empty space in memory

Not quite - `NULL` is a well-defined "nowhere" that doesn't correspond to any valid memory address.

In both C and C++, the `NULL` macro is defined to be a *null pointer constant*, which is a zero-valued integer expression.  C++ also provides the `nullptr` literal, which also evaluates to the null pointer constant.  When a null pointer constant appears in a pointer context, it will be converted to an implementation-defined null pointer *value*.  A null pointer value may or may not be 0-valued, but it is guaranteed to compare unequal to any valid pointer value.

[C 2011 online standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
> ...
> 3     An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
> **void ***, is called a *null pointer constant*.
> <sup>66)</sup> If a null pointer constant is converted to a
> pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal
> to a pointer to any object or function.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>66)) The macro `NULL` is defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other headers) as a null pointer constant; see 7.19</sup>

[C++ 2014 online draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)

> **2.13.7 Pointer literals [lex.nullptr]**
>     *pointer-literal*:
>         `nullptr`
> 1     The pointer literal is the keyword `nullptr`. It is a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. [*Note*: `std::nullptr_t`
> is a distinct type that is neither a pointer type nor a pointer to member type; rather, a prvalue of this type is
> a null pointer constant and can be converted to a null pointer value or null member pointer value. See 4.10
> and 4.11. — *end note* ]
> **4.10 Pointer conversions [conv.ptr]**
> 1     A *null pointer constant* is an integer literal (2.13.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.
> A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the *null pointer value* of that type
> and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type. Such a conversion
> is called a *null pointer conversion*. Two null pointer values of the same type shall compare equal. The
> conversion of a null pointer constant to a pointer to cv-qualified type is a single conversion, and not the
> sequence of a pointer conversion followed by a qualification conversion (4.4). A null pointer constant of
> integral type can be converted to a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`. [ *Note:* The resulting prvalue is not a
> null pointer value. — *end note* ]
> ...
> **18.2 Types [support.types]**
> ...
> 3     The macro `NULL` is an implementation-defined C++ null pointer constant in this International Standard
> (4.10).<sup>194</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>194) Possible definitions include 0 and 0L, but not (void*)0</sup>

To hammer some points home:

1. The `NULL` macro, `nullptr` literal (C++ only), and null pointer *constant* are always 0-valued;
2. The null pointer *value* does not have to be 0-valued;
3. The null pointer *value* will never equal a valid memory address;
4. It's the compiler's job to map the null pointer *constant* in your source code to the equivalent null pointer *value* in the generated machine code; as the programmer, you don't (generally) need to worry about the actual null pointer *value* on your implementation;
5. Since a null pointer constant is always 0-valued, comparing a pointer value against `0` should be equivalent to comparing it against `NULL` or `nullptr`.